# What will be the approach gaussian integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse

Consider the ring Z[√-2022] = {a + b√-2022 : a, b ∈ Z}. The number of elements in this ring having multiplicative inverse is (A) 2. (B) 3. (C) 4. (D) infinite.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: As @EkeneE. comments, the style of this site is that question-askers do explain what they have tried... Also, that ring is not what most people call the Gaussian integers, which would be $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$, although, yes, there's a resemblance.